# Invertir un Array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

El ejercicio es:

> Dado un número entero, crear una función que lo invierta y retorne como array.

Este es el código que tengo, pero no logro entender por qué no funciona.

```
function numeros(number){

number += '';

let resultado = number.split('');    
                       
let lastIndex = resultado.length-1;

for(let i = 0; i<resultado.length; i++){        

    resultado[i] = resultado[lastIndex];

    lastIndex-=1; 
}

return resultado;
```

Veo que, si le paso a la función el número 12345, por ejemplo, me devuelve [54345].
Ya sé que existen otras formas de hacerlo e incluso podría no complicarme la vida y usar `reverse()`, pero quisiera entender por qué no funciona mi código.

Comment: Hey! Con invertirlo entiendo que si el input es `12345` el output deberia ser `[54321]` Correcto?

Comment: Para tu información, hay una forma más simple de decrementar (en 1), es `lastIndex--`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(let i = 0; i<resultado.length; i++){        
    resultado[i] = resultado[lastIndex];
    lastIndex-=1; 
}
```

Él código anterior funciona con la primera mitad del array, ya que la segunda mitad la vas modificando en el camino.

Por esto si haces `numeros(123)` obtienes como respuesta `323`. Al principio colocas el 3 como inicial y al final ese inicial (ahora 3) lo pones al final

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```js
function numeros(number){
  let respuesta = [];
  number = String(number);

  for(let i = number.length -1 ; i>=0; i--){        
    respuesta.push(number[i]);
  }
  return respuesta;
}

console.log(numeros(123))
```

O más sencillo:

```js
function numeros(number){
    return Array.from(String(number)).reverse();
}

console.log(numeros(123))
```

Comment: Ya entendí dónde tenía el error. Claramente ya era hora de dormir cuando me puse a hacer el ejercicio jajajaj. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

El problema aquí es que estás modificando el arreglo mientras lo ejecutas. Digamos que es un tema de concurrencia.

Corre el código mentalmente y lo notarás:

```
resultado[4] = resultado[0]
resultado[3] = resultado[1]
resultado[2] = resultado[2]
resultado[1] = resultado[3] // pero resultado[3] es ahora resultado[1]
resultado[0] = resultado[4] // pero resultado[4] es ahora resultado[0]
```

Para que no tengas estos problemas, usa un arreglo auxiliar, evita hacer los reemplazos en el objeto en que estás trabajando.

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones el código corregido para demostrar que la solución funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes que crear una función sí o sí yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```js
const arrayInicial = [1, 2, 3];

function reverseArray(array) {
    const arrayInverso = [];

    for (let i = array.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
       arrayInverso.push(array[i]);
    }

    return arrayInverso;
}

console.log(reverseArray(arrayInicial));
```

Si no es necesario crear una función y simplemente debes invertir el orden, puedes usar:

```js
const arrayInicial = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(arrayInicial.reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

Revirtiendo el `for` e inicializar un array para almacenar el resultado al revés lo lograrías:

```js
function numeros(number) {
  number += '';
  let resultado = number.split('');
  let revertido = [];

  for (let i = resultado.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    revertido.push(resultado[i]);
  }

  return revertido;
}

console.log(numeros(123))
```

O también algo más sencillo:

```js
function numeros(number) {
  return number.toString().split('').reverse()
}

console.log(numeros(123));
```